Best Approach to Refacing Fireplace
This is my first post and I'm hoping I don't sound too ignorant with my question.
Background - I am renovating my living room and would like to reface our brick fireplace with a thin stone veneer. I eventually plan on installing a set of fireplace doors, a stone hearth, & stone type mantle.
Concern - the fireplace is slightly larger at bottom than the rest and I'm wondering the best approach to prepping the surface for the stone veneer; do I attach cement board to make the rest of the fireplace match the bottom or do I just trowel on additional thinset directly onto the brick? I have attached some photos of the fireplace to show what I'm facing.
Hope anyone can provide some insightful ideas and opinions.

Anthony
[]1


Your idea of using cement board is a good one except for the areas around the hearth opening. A lot of these boards have filler in them and may not stand the heat. Consider framing the top and sides of the hearth opening with a fireproof material.

There are a few possible ways to do the stone. Layers of thinset is one option, but it takes some skill to get nicely flat surface.
I would add layers of cement board. Attaching with some thinset and concrete screw anchors
Then thinset my veneer stone on.

Thank you for your advice, I appreciate it!
